# Firebase firestore @PropertyName not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firestore my Pojo class filed has a different name than firestore, this is why I used `@PropertyName("Email")` but firestore mapper not mapping the fileds, where i making the mistake?

```
GmailCredentials.java

public class GmailCredentials {

   private String email;
   private String password;


   public GmailCredentials() {
   }

   @PropertyName("Email")
   public String getEmail() {
      return email;
   }
   @PropertyName("Password")
   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }
   @PropertyName("Email")
   public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
   }
   @PropertyName("Password")
   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }
}
```

This is how i am reading data from firebase in kotlin

```
val taskFirebae = Firebase.firestore.collection("AppSettings").document("jt86iH0kJyNhOHftv7DF").get()

            val result = Tasks.await(taskFirebae)
           val gmailCredentials=  result.toObject(GmailCredentials::class.java)


if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                Log.d(TAG," ${result.data?.toString()}")
                Log.d(TAG,"emil ${gmailCredentials?.email}")
                Log.d(TAG,"password ${gmailCredentials?.password}")
            }
```

[image]

[image: Screen shot of logs, you can see data is comping from firebase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad i was making a mistake `GmailCredentials` is map, so first you have to get `GmailCredentials` then you get `email` and `password`, you can use Map or create new java and encapsulate the GamilCredentials inside that class e.g.

```
public
class AppSettings {

    @PropertyName("GmailCredentials")
    public GmailCredentials gmailCredentials;

    public AppSettings() {
    }
}
```

Then you can get like this

```
val result = Tasks.await(taskFirebae)
           val gmailCredentials=  result.toObject(AppSettings::class.java)

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                Log.d(TAG, ""+{result.data})
                Log.d(TAG,"emil ${gmailCredentials?.gmailCredentials?.email}")
                Log.d(TAG,"password ${gmailCredentials?.gmailCredentials?.password}")
            }
```